# How Django TemplateResponse handle multi templates

Tags: django, django-templates

The Django doc says `TemplateResponse.template` can be a sequence of template names. Then if there are multi templates, which of the templates will be rendered?

In other words, how does `TemplateResponse` handle multiple templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should behave the same way as [`render_to_string()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut), which is: choose the first that exists.

Comment: jep it can be a tuple of strings, the first existing template is used

Answer (score -1):

TemplateResponse objects retain the details of the template and context that was provided by the view to compute the response. So its controlled by View.

You can also override this method SimpleTemplateResponse.resolve_template(template) to customize the template rendering

Ref:
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/